# How to search inside three paths and copy the name on a file.list

Tags: powershell

I am wondering if there is better way to make a script on PowerShell these instructions:

1. Search on 3 paths. Ex.

   ```
   $LOGDIRS="C:\NETiKA\GED\Production\RI\log";"C:\NETiKA\GED\Test\RI\log";"C:\NETiKA\Tomcat-8.0.28\logs"
   ```
2. Find all files that are older than 7 days and copy on a file that I will call file.list . EX. > C:\Test\file.list
3. When I copied on my file.list, I need to search all the name of the files and delete them.

> Apparently when you have more than thousands of file, this is the
>   fastest way to delete.

```
$LOGDIRS=C:/NETiKA/GED/Production/RI/log;C:/NETiKA/GED/Test/RI/log;C:/NETiKA/Tomcat-8.0.28/logs
$KEEP=-7

Get-ChildItem -Path $LOGDIRS -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-Object FullName > files.list |
    Foreach-Object {
        if ($_.LastAccessTime -le (get-date).adddays($KEEP)) {
            remove-item -recurse -force $_
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hey, we would really like to help you solving your problems. But StackOverflow isnt a free Code-Generator. So please offer an Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you done until this point.

Comment: For help with your code: show your code. For finding a PowerShell tutoral: please use your preferred search engine.

Comment: Hello @Paxz, you are perfectly wright! I was just a bit shamed on what I wrote, I am not very good on coding, but I am very greedy to learn^^ $LOGDIRS=C:/NETiKA/GED/Production/RI/log;C:/NETiKA/GED/Test/RI/log;C:/NETiKA/Tomcat-8.0.28/logs $KEEP=-7 Get-ChildItem -Path $LOGDIRS -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object FullName > files.list | Foreach-Object {if ($_.LastAccessTime -le (get-date).adddays($KEEP)) {remove-item -recurse -force $_}}; –

Comment: Oh wow I already get -4
It seem on this website people like to dissatisfy easily.

Comment: Please post your code by editing your question. Not in a comment. Downvotes are used to indicate that your question does not meet the standards that some users think questions should meet. In this case I imagine that most of them come from the fact that you did not show any code and as a general rule people are expected to make at least some effort before they ask questions here.

Comment: So looking at your code, first, strings should be enclosed in 's or "s. Second, comma (,) is the seperator for array objects. Not the semi-colon (;). Third, once you have a proper array of strings google for `Powershell foreach loop`

Comment: Thanks guys for you help and correction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help you get started.

```
$path1 = "E:\Code\powershell\myPS\2018\Jun"
$path2 = "E:\Code\powershell\myPS\2018\Jun\compareTextFiles"
$path3 = "E:\Code\powershell\myPS\2018\May"
$allFiles = dir $path1, $path2, $path3 -File

$fileList = New-Item -type file file.list -Force

$keep = -7
$allFiles | foreach {
    if ($_.LastAccessTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays($keep)) {
        "$($_.FullName) is older than 7 days"
        $_.FullName.ToString() | Out-File $fileList -Append
    }
    else {
        "$($_.FullName) is new"
    }
}
```

You can add deletion in the code in `IF Block` if you wish or check the file and do it later on. Your code has many issues which are very basic to PowerShell, e.g: once you use `Select-Object` the next pipeline will only receive the property you selected. You have tried using LastAccessTime in later pipe when you only selected to go ahead with FullName property.

Also, redirecting to a file and again using pipeline looks very messy.

Comment: Hello @Ketanbhout,
thanks for your help, you gave me a really good input to continue to perfect my code! :)

Answer (score 0):

- Remove-Item accepts piped input and a
- Where will filter the age
- to first check what **would** be deleted I appended a `-WhatIf` to the `Remove-Item`

---

```
$LOGDIRS="C:\NETiKA\GED\Production\RI\log","C:\NETiKA\GED\Test\RI\log","C:\NETiKA\Tomcat-8.0.28\logs"
$KEEP=-7

Get-ChildItem -Path $LOGDIRS -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object LastAccessTime -le ((get-date).AddDays($KEEP)) 
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $_ -Whatif
```